# Firebird similar to Digit constraint

Tags: sql, firebird, sql-like

I'm trying to set a constraint on my table that makes it so that the column `player_id` is formatted like "Vxxxxxx" where `x` is a digit from [0-9]. Would the following  be right?

```
player_id SIMILAR TO 'V[:DIGIT:][:DIGIT:][:DIGIT:][:DIGIT:][:DIGIT:][:DIGIT:]'
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct, but I do not have a Firebird install at hand to check it right now.

Note that you can shorten it to `'V[:DIGIT:]{6}'`. This makes it easier to read as well, because you don't have to count the number of digit-classes.